# Unable to train Tesseract in Ubuntu

Tags: tesseract

I am new in `Tesseract`,  I am trying to train Tesseract in Ubuntu, I am using `JTessBoxEditor` for trainer, I have successfully generated `.tif` and `.box` file, but I am unable to Trainer data using it,  during JTessBoxEditor Trainer, I don't know which Tesseract Executable location need to select for training data.
Can some please help here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to [build](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract) the Tesseract training tools first. Their installation directory can be determined by executing `which tesseract` command.